# How do I remove an extra dock in cairo dock?

Tags: cairo-dock

I have two cairo docks, one is at the bottom , one is at the top of my desktop.
How do I remove the top dock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete all the items on the unwanted dock. To do so, just right click on each icon and go to "remove." When they are all gone, the dock will disappear.

There might be another way via the settings, but Cairo dock's are so utterly confusing that I couldn't find one.

Comment: agreed , i am using docky now ...

Answer (score 3):

If the dock you wish to delete is not your main dock, just right-click it, go to *Cario-Dock*, select *Delete this dock* and then confirm.